# caractére opcional em máscara com Jquery maskedInput não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masked-input

Em um formulário que estou desenvolvendo, um dos campos que o usuário precisa preencher é o de celular, e como o celular de algumas regiões do Brasil possuem 9 dígitos estou usando a biblioteca [jQuery MaskedInput](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) para formatar a entrada de dados.

O problema é que quando eu crio a máscara `$("#celular").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");` o caractére **?** aparece no input desta forma `(__) ____-____?_`, o que não era para acontecer.

Eu utilizei esta mesma formatação em um sistema anterior que funcionou perfeitamente, não consigo entender porque neste caso não está funcionando.

O plugin que estou usando é esse aqui **digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin** 
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: poderia colocar o código q tens até agora?

Comment: Posta seu código pois fiz um teste com sua mascara e funciona, da uma olhada = https://jsfiddle.net/4xon0s6e/

Comment: No HTML está assim:

<input type="text" name="celular" id="celular" placeholder="DDD + CELULAR" value=""/>


E no javascript está assim:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#celular").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
});

O que eu acho estranho que é em um outro sistema meu está funcionando tudo ok, e neste aqui ele fica (__) ____-____?_

Comment: [Aqui](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/aOeGKG) também funcionou. Pode dar mais detalhes do seu código?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo seu exemplo era para funcionar.

Já trabalhei em vários projetos e sempre que usamos um plugin de mascara, damos preferencia para http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Esse eu garanto, e modo de usar é muito parecido, na minha opinião é o melhor!

Abraço
Espero ter te ajudado