# Mascara JQuery com telefone de 8 ou 9 digitos

Tags: jquery, mask

Estou utilizando o mask no Jquery para formatar o campo de telefone com 8 oi 9 dígitos, mas infelizmente eu só consigo deixar 8 ou 9. Se eu deixar 9, quando o usuário digitar 8 ele apaga todo o campo, alguém sabe como proceder? Grato desde já.

Comment: [caractére opcional em máscara com Jquery maskedInput não funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81581/91) e [Nono dígito fixo em máscara](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70233/91)

Comment: Consigui resolver com a pergunta do colega acima. Obrigado.

Comment: Qual delas a primeira ou a segunda?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (mas diferente): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46672/132